# Elasticsearch Regular expression for first 2 digit numbers but should not be specific number

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

Looking for regular expression with below conditions
1)First digit must be number
2)But first 2 digits must not be 05 or 09
3)Followed by any number of characters

Example:
14SBC is valid
1ABC is valid
05ABVC is not valid
09ASC is not valid
0ASC is valid

Comment: Please also add what you tried. It is important to see where exactly the issue might be.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do what you want :
`(0[0-46-8a-zA-Z]|[1-9])[0-9a-zA-Z]+`

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/zRCOgG/2)

**Edit :** changed the answer according to @WiktorStribiżew's comment

Comment: [ES regex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) does not support lookarounds and shorthand character classes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh well... Didn't know that ^^ I'll find something else.

Comment: Unless OP states where exactly the issue is, it is not possible to *find* anything. If it is used in a tokenizer, then the regex must conform to a Java regex syntax, else, it should conform to Lucene regex syntax. The question is too unclear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I see your point. However I like to propose something first, and see how it works out for OP. It may also help him to clarify is need. But I guess it is not the place to debate this ^^

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

`"(0[^59]|[1-9]).*"`

Assuming "any number" includes 0 and "character" is anything except `\n`.

Comment: ES regex does not support `^` and `$` anchors, since ES regex is always anchored by default.

Comment: Looking for something similar